# Which edges (h->l or l->h) does this circuit detect?

Tags: digital-logic

Which edges (h->l or l->h) does this circuit detect? When I simulate it, the output voltage is constant, so it does not seem like it would detect any edges, which I did not expect.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us your output trace and show the timebase settings.

Comment: if you didn't set `td` then the inputs of `A4` will always see `V(in) & !V(in)`, or `0 & 1 = 0`, or `1` for NAND. If you want edge detection then you need to set `td`.

Comment: NAND gates with one input always low always produce a high on the output irrespective of what the other input is at. Try using proper logic levels too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Andy aka has pointed out that the outputs of A1, A2 and A3 are always high. I think you meant them to be inverters, which requires that one of the inputs should be permanently *high*, not low. That explains why your graphs don't show any pulses. I'm ashamed that this didn't occur to me. That said, here's the rest of my original answer:

The combined propagation delay of A1, A2 and A3 is probably a few tens of nanoseconds, so any pulse you expect to see at the output of A4 will be that long. This is *tiny* compared to the time units you've specified for your pulse generator, and I suspect that if you are graphing time scales of the order of hundreds of milliseconds, then output pulses are too short to appear on the graphs.

Which transition is being detected, rising or falling? Well, in the condition where V1 is a steady high or low, the two inputs to A4 are always inverted with respect to each other, due to the odd number of inverters in the chain A1, A2, A3. Therefore, the natural state of output of NAND gate A4 is high.

If V1 starts high, bringing it low will not change that. Both inputs to A4 momentarily become low, and A4 output stays high. Later, when the delayed inverted signal also arrives at A4, it simply restores the state where the two inputs to A4 are inverted w.r.t each other. A4 output never changes during the transition of V1 from high to low.

If V1 starts low, though, things are different. If V1 then rises, both inputs to A4 become simultaneously, and momentarily, high. A4's output will go low and stay there until the other signal eventually arrives, to restore the status quo of mutually inverted signals.

Therefore this circuit detects a rising edge.

Comment: Can you explain how A3's NAND output can ever produce anything but logic level 1 (with an input at logic zero)? In other words, when you say *"the two inputs to A4 are always inverted with respect to each other"* - how can that ever be true? How can the *"combined propagation delay of A1, A2 and A3 is probably a few tens of nanoseconds"* be true if those NAND gates each have an input at logic zero?

Comment: @Andyaka Good point. You have humbled me. I'll put a note in.

Comment: @Andyaka While true with real gates, in LTspice the 8th pin (ground pin) is always connected to `GND` if unused. Unused inputs are also connected to the 8th pin, so that the gates can be used with 1-, 2-, ..., 5- inputs without extra connections. Here, the pin below the gate, but off-side, is the 8th pin and is unconnected in all cases, and the grounded ones are simply detected to be connected at `GND`, too. This means the gates will act as [inverters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wIMu.png) here. For a logic low an explicit voltage is needed. So, here, the cause is the missing `td` (delay).

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you present has a *hazard*. That is there are two or more paths between the input(s) and output(s) that *race* against each other. Depending upon the propagation delays, (and the set-up and hold times of components) the output may or may not include certain transitions when given a particular input.

In practice, manufacturers of integrated circuits are often able to control propagation delays within the IC such that the circuit behaves in some desired way. However, circuits manufactured under such controlled conditions are not guaranteed to work the same way when they are implemented with separately manufactured discrete components.